# Find the next number divided by 8?

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Hi this is an interview question.

For any given number calculate next number which is divisible by 8.

i.e. If given number is `43`, our algorithm should produce `48` as result. If number is already divisible by `8` it should say `Number already divisible by 8` and produce next number divisible by 8.

I suggest them that any number which is divisible by `8` have last three bits as `0` (LSB+2,LSB+1,LSB). But I am not able to give exact solution.

What I said is right approach to solve this problem or we can go for some smarter solution?
I need to do this with bit manipulation.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan... Thanks but I need to write program for that... Do they support programs there??

Comment: I think the interviewer wants to check you're able to write such  a simple program.

Comment: @fjardon... It depends...Between I can write simple programs...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're on the right track.

```
int next8(int n) {
    int bits = n & 7; // give us the distance to the previous 8
    if (bits == 0) printf("Number already divisible by 8");
    return n + (8-bits);
}
```

(Note: I hate it when functions that are supposed to be pure print something, but the task demands so. Sorry.)

Comment: +1 for accurately doing it "with bit manipulation", as asked.

Comment: Nah, revert the edit. This function shouldn't print. It should return (and it now doesn't return a value anymore, which is a bug.) The question is how to find out the number, not how to use printf().

Comment: @NikosC., My comments make the point I want, thank you very much. I'd suggest you reread the question.

Comment: When I am trying to shift the bits (i<<3), I am not getting correct result... I got where I was doing wrong.

Comment: @StoryTeller The question is about finding out the next number, not how to use printf(). Hardcoding printf() statements inside the function is very poor design.

Comment: @NikosC., The use of `printf` addresses the requirement of printing it. It's ugly, but that's what is asked.

Comment: @Ingo It still shouldn't print anything. That should be done in next8()'s caller. And it's still bugged. It doesn't return a value, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @NikosC. Your advise has my full symphaty, as you can see from my edit. Anyway, the tasks is to write an algorithm that produces the next multiple of 8 **and** print something when the argument is already a multiple of 8.

Comment: @Ingo It's still bugged. You have *undefined behavior*. Keep the printf(), but the bug is still there.

Comment: YOu botched it! Please don't do that, if you can't understand. The task was to retrun the **next** multiple of 8 in any case.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sure, so? ... please ignore Nico's wrong solution.

Comment: @Ingo, yeah sorry. I should pay attention to who made the edit next time.

Comment: Still waiting for @NikosC. to tell me where the undefined behaviour is. Though I am not sure if it is oky to pass no vararg elements to printf.

Comment: Nowhere. I was just confused :-O

Answer (score 7):

`next = current + 8 - (current % 8)`

Comment: Gives 16 for 8, when it should give 8

Comment: You're right ---- this is indeed silly. +1 for reading the question until the end.

Comment: @Ingo Next number divisible by 8 after 8 is 16 indeed.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with a while loop:

```
if number % 8 == 0
  already divisible by 8

while number % 8 != 0
  ++number
```

This is `O(1)`, since 8 is a constant, but we can do better with the following formula:

```
if number % 8 == 0
  already divisible by 8

number = number + 8 - number % 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check is correct, to check it you can perform a bitwise AND with 7 and make sure it is 0 (X & 7 == 0).
To get the next number - Shift right by 3, add 1 and shift back ( ((X >> 3) + 1) << 3 )

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
   int n;
   printf("\n Enter the number:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   if(n==8 && n%8==0)
   printf("%d it is already divisible by 8",n);
   else
   {
      printf("not divsible by 8 so nearest number is:");
      i=n/8;
      i++;
      n=i*8;
      printf("%d is next number divisible by 8",n);         
   }
}
```

you can try this which is one of the solution

Thankyou.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.. Thanks for your help.. I asked using bit-manipulation...